# python : image generator from a group in a range

Tags: python, range, nft, group

I am new here.
I found a code online and I am trying to fix some things.

I want my groups to use/see all files inside designated folder  (*.png) for that group , not only these I typed.

group1 = [
r"D:/IM/1x/5_0.png",
r"D:/IM/1x/5_1.png",
r"D:/IM/1x/5_2.png"

Group 2 is using files located

D:/IM/2x/

it can be 100x more pictures inside this folder(1x), I do not want to locate every single one as separate line

Here is the code.   Thank you very much for any help.
If it does not make sense, please ask.

```
from PIL import Image
group1 = [
  r"D:/IM/1x/5_0.png",
  r"D:/IM/1x/5_1.png",
  r"D:/IM/1x/5_2.png",
  r"D:/IM/1x/5_3.png",
  r"D:/IM/1x/5_4.png",

]

group2 = [
  r"D:/IM/2x/4_0.png",
  r"D:/IM/2x/4_1.png",
  r"D:/IM/2x/4_2.png"

]

group3 = [
  r"D:/IM/3x/3_1.png"

]
counter = 1

def createImage(a,b,c, counter):
  first = group1[a]
  second = group2[b]
  third = group3[c]

  image01 = Image.open(first).convert("RGBA")
  image02 = Image.open(second).convert("RGBA")
  image03 = Image.open(third).convert("RGBA")


  intermediate = Image.alpha_composite(image01, image02)
  intermediate2 = Image.alpha_composite(intermediate, image03)


  name = "D:/DONE/" + str(counter) + ".png"
  intermediate2.save(name)

for a in range(10):
  for b in range(3):
    for c in range(1):
               createImage(a,b,c, counter)
               counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: please explain what is group and why group?

Comment: I’m not sure why group was used in this code. My guess is to group objects from different folders in different groups

Comment: Have you tried using `glob.glob` to list all the files in the directory? See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: Hi. Not yet. 

How would I write it for a group 1 For a folder in d:/IM/1x/

Comment: I got it. It’s working. Thank you.